# Why can't I load actual data in the expansion panels in flutter of "Only static members can be accesed in initializers"?

Tags: flutter, dart

I looked at the official docs [flutter expansion panels](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html) as a reference to building my own. I'm having trouble making them work AND work with my data. I have tried passing some of the data my widget receives in its constructor to be used when the panel list is being generated. I hope this code fragments are enough, if not I can add more.

Here is where the error pops up (when trying to reference widget.contracts)

```
class FinancialTabContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Contract> contracts;
  final Person travelOfficer;

  FinancialTabContent({this.contracts, this.travelOfficer});

  @override
  _FinancialTabContentState createState() => _FinancialTabContentState();
}

class _FinancialTabContentState extends State<FinancialTabContent> {
  List<ExpandableItem> expansionPanels = generateExpansionPanels(widget.contracts);  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
```

This is what I intended to use to build the panel list, it's placed inside the _FinancialTabContentState

```
Widget _buildPanelList() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          expansionPanels[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: expansionPanels.map<ExpansionPanel>((ExpandableItem item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            ....
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
```

Here's the code for the expandable item

```
import 'contract.dart';

class ExpandableItem {
  ExpandableItem({    
    this.isExpanded = false,
    this.panelData
  });

  bool isExpanded;
  Contract panelData; 
}

List<ExpandableItem> generateExpansionPanels(List<Contract> panelsData) {
  return List.generate(panelsData.length, (int index) {
    return ExpandableItem(
      panelData: panelsData[index],
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line to within the `build` method:

```
List<ExpandableItem> expansionPanels = generateExpansionPanels(widget.contracts);
```

Or do this in the [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) method if you want it only done once:

```
class _FinancialTabContentState extends State<FinancialTabContent> {
    List<ExpandableItem> expansionPanels;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        expansionPanels = generateExpansionPanels(widget.contracts);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
}
```

Read the docs on [State](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) which describe in detail the lifecycle of a Widget.

Comment: I tried the first thing myself but then the panels won't expand(tried it again in case i maybe missed something). Doing the constructor thing gives me the same error.

Comment: Try to make the list non-final, and assign it on the body of the constructor rather than the initializer.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm confused. What do you mean by this?

Comment: The getter 'contracts' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: contracts

this is what i get

Comment: Sorry, I am also not good with Flutter :) see the edited answer, now it should work... Make sure to read the docs (link provided in answer) so you don't get stuck on basic issues like this.

Comment: Thanks alot for bearing with me and helping me out! Cheers!

Comment: On StackOverflow, you thank people by upvoting :) hope it worked for you now!